# Preventing Tabs from TabLayout to show in front of the app's Toolbar in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, tabs, toolbar, androidx

### Summary

I need to have 3 Tabs right below the App's Toolbar, preferably without a line separating the Tabs and the Toolbar. But they are shown in front of the bar, hiding it nearly completely.

### Context

I´m working on an Android App, with a DrawerLayout/NavigationView opening up from the side, where you can navigate between pages, with one of them containing a few Tabs at the top, right below the Toolbar.

I've tried putting the TabLayout into the page, but the tabs always end up behind or in front of the Toolbar.

Putting the TabLayout into the AppBarLayout where the Toolbar is didn't seem to work as well, the tabs were correctly shown below the Toolbar, but that Tab's content was shown inside the Toolbar as well.

### Toolbar and FragmentContainer in main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat  
android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

### Sample TabLayout in page1.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">  

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_content_tab_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:text="News"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:text="NoNews"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:text="Dreams"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >
```

Comment: ,**I need to have 3 Tabs right below the App's Toolbar, preferably without a line separating the Tabs and the Toolbar.** You want to implement this:http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/05/material-design-tab-in-xamarin-android.html. If not, please post some screenshot here.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT The tab layout is supposed to be part of the start page, but not of any of the other pages, while the toolbar is defined  on the mainlayout. With everything i´ve tried, the Tabs arent visible because they are behind the toolbar and not below it. 
Maybe its not a problem with the Tabs, but the layout. since it appears that every page is centered on the whole screen with the toolbar on top of it, so the toolbar is hiding the top part on any of the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kept looking around for a solution to my problem and stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32280417/10922025) answer to a similar question.

I moved the **Toolbar**, **Tablayout** ( its visibility set to "gone") and the **Fragment** **Container** into its own xml called **app_bar_main**.

Then I included it in my **Main** **Layout**:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The Fragment which is supposed to show the Tabs implements the following **overrides**:

```
    public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.home_content_pager);
        viewPager.Adapter = new HomeAdapter(ChildFragmentManager);

        tabLayout = Activity.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }


    public override void OnDestroyView()
    {
        tabLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        base.OnDestroyView();
    }
```

The **OnDestroyView** override sets the TabLayout's Visibility to Gone, so all the other Fragments are not displaying the Tabs.

This way, the Tablayout exists across all of the Fragments, and can be displayed and filled with the chosen Tabs and be hidden when not needed.

*I'm using com.google.android.material and the AndroidX NuGet Packages and am fairly new to Xamarin.Android, but I hope this helps someone with a similar problem.*